# Hollow box program with user input. Issue: Works for odd number input, not even

Tags: java, for-loop, formatting

If the user input is odd and within the range it works fine. Can't seem to figure out how to get it to work with even number input though.

I've seen that there is an "easier" way to do this program on other posts but I got this on my own before having to look up any issues and want to see if there is any way I can make this work through this method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7_3{

  public static void main(String args []){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userStart;
    int countA=1, countB=1, rowsColumns;

    System.out.println("Do you want to start?");

    userStart = input.next().charAt(0);

    while (userStart == 'Y' || userStart == 'y'){

      System.out.println("How many rows/columns? (5-21)");

      rowsColumns = input.nextInt();

      while (rowsColumns < 5 || rowsColumns > 21){

       System.out.println("Invalid range. Reenter (5-21)");

       rowsColumns = input.nextInt();

      }//end while3

      for(countA = 1; countA <= rowsColumns; countA++){

        System.out.println("");

        for(countB = 1; countB <= rowsColumns; countB++){

          if((rowsColumns % countA) == 0 || (rowsColumns % countB) == 0)){

            System.out.print("*");

          }//end if 

          else{

            System.out.print("1");

          }//end else

        }//end for2


      }//end for

      System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue? (Y/N)");

      userStart = input.next().charAt(0);

    }//end while

  }//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `if((rowsColumns % countA) == 0 || (rowsColumns % countB) == 0))` gives wrong results.

`if(countA==1 || countA == rowsColumns || countB == 1 || countB == rowsColumns)` works for both odd and even numbers.

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I saw posted up around a few times. It totally works for me. BUT I was just wondering if there was any way I could alter the solution I came up with to get the required results.

Comment: I don't think there can be an alternative solution because it's not that complicated.